# Uber api to get driver history

Tags: android, ios, odoo

I am integrating Uber API in iOS and odoo platform and my client required every driver's history - like how much driver earn in a day or week.

So there is any API or alternate solutions to get earning history of driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every driver's history like how much driver earn in a day or week. So there is any api or alternate solutions to get earning history of driver

**Ans**

**It is not possible**,any api does not provide the private Information it is against to the rules, if you need this type of request you need to request to Uber.

in Uber we can get distance, amount , available taxi thats all

Comment: Thanks Anbu, for replying, actually my client is a uber partner and he has hundreds of vehicles and drivers thats why he needs each driver's history. It is possible or not.

Comment: no it is not possible bro, if you need for this particlular concept , you need to  customize (request to uber on offically), there is no public api for this